# Selecting radiobuttons populated within asp.net RadioButtonList with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Hello and thanks in advance for the communal help I always find here. I have been tinkering around with what should seem a pretty straight forward task even for a jQuery newb as myself.
I have a radiobuttonlist control bound to a collection:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radBtnLstPackageSelector" runat="server" 
 CssClass="PackageS">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My form does have several other controls of the same type;
Now, the challenge is to select and wire up a on Click event for every radiobutton from the radBtnLstPackageSelector.
I have tried several approaches such as:

```
var results1 = $(".PackageS").children("input");
var results1 = $(".PackageS").children("input[type=radiobutton");
var results1 = $("table.PackageS > input[type=radiobutton");
```

with no luck...
Your help would be great right now!
~m

Comment: Open page in webbrowser, rightclick and choose view source. That's the HTML source which JavaScript/jQuery sees. Base your selectors on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also target it using the IDs of the elements ASP.NET will generate (though this isn't the best solution and may change in future versions of ASP.NET):

```
$(function() {
    $("[id*=radBtnLstPackageSelector]:radio").click(function() {
        alert( $(this).val() );  // Alerts the value of the radio button.
    });
});
```

All IDs inside `radBtnLstPackageSelector` will be in the form of
`[other naming containers if there are any]_radBtnLstPackageSelector_[index of the element 1..last]`

Answer (score 1):

So you want a click event on each radio button in `.PackageS`. Is that right?

If so, do this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".PackageS :radio").click(function() {
        alert( $(this).val() );  // Alerts the value of the radio button.
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".PackageS :radio").each(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });
this worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @user194881: If this answer was helpful, you should click the check mark next to it to mark it as the answer in case someone with a similar problem comes across the this question.